# Confused with awk! Getting: 'cannot open "" for output'

Tags: awk

Hi I have 2 files in my working directory. One is a simple file given by:

```
$ cat file2 
START 
Unix 
Linux 
START 
Solaris 
Aix 
SCO
```

And I have a 6000 line xml file called dblp_1_76007.xml.

When I do

```
awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' file2
```

it seems to work perfectly fine but if I change the filename to the xml that is when I change it to:

```
awk '/START/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' dblp_1_76007.xml
```

I get the following error message:

> awk: cannot open "" for output (No such file or directory)

I was originally trying to do

```
awk '/<www/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' dblp_1_76007.xml
```

to split each line starting with www in the xml and this also gives me the same error message.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: If you find yourself `awk`ing XML quite often, there's special tools for that, for example [XMLgawk](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an initial value for `x`

```
awk -v x=F0 '/<www/{x="F"++i};{print > x}' dblp_1_76007.xml
```

or only start outputting at the first `www`:

```
awk '/<www/ {x="F"++i}; i > 0 {print > x}' dblp_1_76007.xml
```

Comment: Thanks! I understood the problem. Since file2 had 'START' as the first word F1 was getting created and the command ran without any problem. But that was not the case with my XML. Thanks again for the help :)